# UiAutomator 2.0 and Eclipse

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, android-uiautomator

Is there any way to compile *UiAutomator 2.0* with Eclipse and Ant?

I have added the `android.jar` and `uitautomator.jar` files from *Android-23* but to no avail. Eclipse still does not see *UiAutomator 2.0* specific methods like `UiObject2`.

I have also attempted to build a `.jar` file with Ant in Gradle which generates the required `.jar` file but only works for *UiAutomator 1.0*. I used the method detailed [here](http://blog.denevell.org/android-uiautomator-gradle.html).

I know Android now officially only supports Android Studio+Gradle now but my setup requires the usage of a standalone `uiautomator.jar` file that Ant builds, which is not supported (at least as far as I know) with Android Studio and Gradle.

Will appreciate any push in the right direction.

Comment: My advice would be to change your setup to gradle instead of Ant. It will not be strait forward and will result in some hard work but it will save you lots of time. I was using Eclipse and ant when I first started using UiAutomator and it didn't take me long to realise I really had to change to AndroidStudio and Gradle. Handling something as simple as dependencies was a hassle and now it's simple.