# Running UiAutomator 2.0 test cases without USB connected

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle, android-uiautomator, autotest

I'm trying to run UiAutomator 2.0 test cases on my device without USB connected, however it's now based on intrumentation test, unlike UiAutomator 1.0 which supports --nohup option.

two approaches came up to me:
1. looking for a way to run UiA 2.0 without USB connected
2. using UiA 1.0

with no luck on approach 1, I tried to build UiA 1.0 test case with Android Studio and Gradle, however after searching the internet(some links [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32853211/uiautomator-2-0-and-eclipse) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21771425/build-failed-gradle-with-uiautomator-android?rq=1)), it seems that UiA 1.0 doesn't directly support Gradle, I haven't been able to build UiA 1.0 test case successfully using Android Studio and Gradle, does anyone have any idea how to solve this? or going back to UiA 1.0 with Eclipse and giving up UiA 2.0 is the only option for me? thanks in advance for any hints provided!

Comment: I have build UiA 1.0 with gradle sometime ago. some tips are here- http://wiliamsouza.github.io/#/2013/10/30/android-uiautomator-gradle-build-system

Comment: nice tips u got there, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `adb shell nohup am instrument -w ...` to run your tests without USB connected.

The `nohup` command ensures that `am instrument` continues running after the shell session terminates (e.g. when you disconnect your USB connection).